# how to make ext4 file system block group have block group descriptor and super block

Tags: ext4

I found in the android, data partition and system partition of ext4 file system block group, only 0,1,3,5,7 etc have block group descriptor and super block. But in the Linux is all some, can you tell me how to make ext4 file system block group have block group descriptor and super block

Answer (score 1):

this fact is due to the "**sparse_super feature flag**" set in the ext4 filesystem on your android device.
sparse_super feature means that the superblock and group-descriptor table will not be part of every block group. Instead it will just be copied to the block group 0 and 1 and all block groups whose number is a power of 3,5,7

-> So this means it will show up in: 0,1,3,5,7,9,25,27,49...

You can dissable this feature on a filesystem with:

```
    tune2fs -s 0 /dev/...
```

Or while making a new ext4 filesystem:

```
    mke2fs -T ext4 -O ^sparse_super /dev/...
```